# Probability of different card hands

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm looking at doing a game for an upcoming expo and I'm having a hard time with the math for it. I'm wanting to lay out 25 cards (all suited the same so let's say all Hearts) and give out prizes based on what is drawn from the attendees. Each person would get to pick 5 cards. The cards would be laid out on a table in rows/columns of 5. (So like a big square)

My layers of winning would be:
1 pair,
3 of a kind,
4 of a kind,
Straight, and
Royal Flush.

and I'm looking at laying my cards out like so:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\textbf{How Many} & \textbf{Card Type} \\
4 & 2 \\
4 & 3 \\
3 & 4 \\
2 & 5 \\
2 & 6 \\
2 & 7 \\
2 & 8 \\
1 & 9 \\
1 & 10 \\
1 & A \\
1 & J \\
1 & Q \\
1 & K
\end{matrix}
$$
I need to figure out the probability of drawing each of the winning options. Ie., probability of drawing a pair from this layout. Probability of drawing a 3 of a kind from this layout. etc.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What does "lay out" mean in this context?  Are you just saying that someone draws a hand of $5$ cards from this unusual deck?  Something else?  If that's all you meant, then it looks tedious but straight forward.  Things like straights have a lot of cases, for instance.

Comment: How many cards are the players drawing?

Comment: Before you start calculating, notice that a usual deck of cards has no '1' apart from the Ace.

Comment: @AlanAbraham they will get to draw 5 cards.

Comment: @311411 apologies. I guess I didn't get enough sleep last night... I updated to remove those. :)

Comment: @lulu I would lay the cards out on a table face down in rows of five. Is something like this and they would get to pick 5 cards at random: 
X  X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X

Comment: You just need to see if the probabilities are approximately reasonable, so the easiest thing to do here would be to simulate a million hands in your favorite programming language and see what you get.

Comment: I see no purpose to the "laying out".  All you are saying is that we choose $5$ of these cards uniformly at random, right?  Assuming that, where are you having any difficulty?  As I said, the computations are tedious but straight forward (and some of them, royal flush, say, aren't even tedious).

Comment: As a (somewhat) minor point:  in poker, the various types of hands preclude any better hand.  That is to say, a "straight" excludes "straight flush" and, more obviously, a pair excludes three of a kind.    Though I have no idea what you would say about  $22233$ in your set up.  I'd have called that a Full House, but that's not one of your options.

Comment: @lulu I just meant that the card stack would be as I put above. With 4 2's, etc. However, in reference to your question, yes. You will just pick 5 cards at random. I don't think it really matters if they are in a deck on top of each other or laid out on a table, I was just trying to be clear on what was going to happen. :) 
Additionally, yes we would exclude the other winning hands from Poker and it would be based on just the ones I listed. 
I'm not sure how to do the math for this at all. So it being straight forward doesn't help me without knowing how. :)

Comment: There are $\binom {25}5=53130$ hands.  For any desired hand type, count the number of hands of that type.  Divide.  For instance, there is only one possible Royal Flush, so the probability of that is $\frac 1{53130}$.

Comment: @lulu I'll give that a shot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, simulating one million hands yielded these estimates for the probabilities. It looks like the odds are pretty close to those for a full deck, except that the hands three-of-a-kind or better are slightly more likely with the shortened deck.

```
junk            48.50575 %
pair            42.37255 %
two-pair         4.77935 %
3ofkind          3.3505  %
straight         0.68395 %
fullhouse        0.22435 %
4ofakind         0.08135 %
royalstraight    0.0022  %
```

Found with [this Python program.](https://tio.run/##jVLLbtswEDyLX7GXQmSjpNEjCGCgf@GbIBSMRdmMKVLho6kR5NvdJSXbQnqpeBFmd2f2MdPJH4yuz@fBmhGkF9YboxzIcTLWw96aML2cSIparvuYNIccHyclCNmZoL2Dn9A2RVPURbW88vY60ovdEVNcGGnbSriDqoPvMJe2soPBWJAgddTYC1rWrCug7RjBygG8lVxRtiHZjts@ajnsQPR07oFG9gKeGCPZYMXbKqFVQlMlnadpEsaS0lGcinm0KLnMSBN31LXit7BOIMvWBoE9ZHKAhRjHvI0FuBAY@Z@lNEbLZgalXoOP2HpmhQ9WQ27NiSvnLZf7g8//n/3@C2uzJr3xZeQCftArGdvkr0Ef8wKwhlZXcOLSXsEqQf7d3K/gesmszXCUul/QJmGNGfgMzpkVYkNQ6mCCE/ln60O8TpqNdYRsIa4ifcQKF1SyzccniTf5dbv@Nl66t/wdo8vp05ISpI1PmXP95vLTxmCHBY9x/DV0h6IkSRxwoQXoMEaCxSBL7gM6f3SUFdEbyKL4@NJz8Bvflv86AtubrNSe5oBfjnbG9dNIzx7Ua0C3lU9IFUGcF40eNX/A9hJ9xmD@LWfn818)